# SQLalchemy + celery + FastAPI = UnboundExecutionError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery, fastapi

I have a fastapi API that uses sqlalchemy for models and querying against a Postgres database. I'm trying to implement Celery as a task manager, but am running into  and UnboundExecutionError for celery tasks that contain api calls that utilize sqlalchemy. example error below:

UnboundExecutionError('Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper[CampaignORM(campaign)], SQL expression or this Session.

where CampaignORM is a sqlalchemy model.

relevant code:

celery.py creationg of celery instance:

```
celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.conf.broker_url = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL", "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0")
celery.conf.result_backend = os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND", "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0")

app = app_create()
```

app.py with app_create() function defined:

```
def app_create():
    from os import environ
    global _app

    if _app is None:
        _app = FastAPIOffline(
            _app.add_middleware(
            CORSMiddleware,
            allow_origins=['*'],
            allow_methods=['*'],
            allow_headers=['*']
        )
    if not hasattr(_app, 'db'):
        from ..database.schema import engine_init_config, session_init
        drop_all = False
        if "BACKEND_DROPDB" in environ:
            drop_all = bool(environ["BACKEND_DROPDB"])
        _app.logger.info(f"Database Init, Drop Flag: {drop_all}")

        _app.sql_engine = engine_init_config(_app.config, root_content=_app.root_content, 
            drop_all=drop_all)
        _app.db = session_init(_app.sql_engine)

    return _app
```

engine_init_config() and session_init() are defined elsewhere:

```
def engine_init_config(config_dict, verbose=False, root_content=None, drop_all=False, null_pool=False):
    from pathlib import Path

    from sqlalchemy import create_engine

    from ...utils.custom_logger import logger_create

    logger = logger_create()

    if root_content is None:
        root_content = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

    try:
        db_config = config_dict['database']
        db_url = None
        if db_config['type'] == 'sqlite':
            path_db = Path(root_content) / db_config['db']
            if not path_db.parent.exists():
                logger.warning(f"[session_init_config]: Creating missing directory '{path_db.parent}'")
                path_db.parent.mkdir(parents=True)
            db_url = f"sqlite:///{path_db}"  # 'config/content_backend.db'
        elif db_config['type'] == 'postgres':
            db_url = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{db_config['user']}:{db_config['pass']}@{db_config['host']}:{db_config['port']}/{db_config['db']}?sslmode={db_config['sslmode']}"

        # engine creation
        sql_engine = None
        try:
            if null_pool:
                sql_engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=verbose, poolclass=NullPool)
            else:
                sql_engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=verbose)
            if drop_all:
                engine_drop(sql_engine, False)

      
            Base.metadata.create_all(bind=sql_engine)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"[session_init]: Init url '{db_url}' failed. (Error {e})...")
            return None
        return sql_engine

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"[session_init_config]: Missing database configuration strings '{config_dict}'. (Error {e})...")

    return None


def session_init(db_engine):
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    return sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)()
```

finally the task that is causing the error and the campaign_list function it calls:

```
async def campaign_list(campaign_id, user_id, response_offset = 0, response_limit=20, include_prompt=False):
    stmt_retr = (select(schema.CampaignORM, func.count(schema.CampaignORM.campaign_id).over().label("total"))
                 .join(schema.AccessMembershipORM, schema.CampaignORM.access_id == schema.AccessMembershipORM.access_id)
                 .where(schema.AccessMembershipORM.user_id == user_id)
                 )
    

    # perform group to get to just one campaign
    stmt_retr = (stmt_retr.group_by(schema.CampaignORM.campaign_id)
                 .order_by(schema.CampaignORM.timestamp_created.desc())
                 .offset(response_offset).limit(response_limit)
                 )

    campaign_list = []
    total_count = 0
    for db_item, _local_count in app.db.execute(stmt_retr):   # execute for search
        total_count = _local_count
        stmt_retr = (select(schema.CampaignORM.campaign_id, schema.CampaignORM.campaign_type)  # retrieve linked components
                     .where(schema.CampaignORM.component_list_id == db_item.component_list_id)
                     )
        list_components = {x.campaign_id: x.campaign_type for x in app.db.execute(stmt_retr).all()}  # execute for search

        # create new base item
        campaign_info = CampaignIdentifier(...lots of code...)
    return resp_new

@celery.task(name="generate content")
def generate_content(campaign_id, user_id, num_responses, media_type, simulate_only, clone_source, num_historical):
    # retrieve the target campaign
    resp_campaign = async_to_sync(campaign_list)(campaign_id, user_id)
    obj_campaign_source = resp_campaign.campaign_list[0]
   
    return obj_campaing_source
```

a lot of code, I know. The app instance created in celery.py should contain a db session instance with binding, as it's included in the app_create() function, but I'm still getting the unbound error. I've tried disabling pooling on the creation of the session as I saw suggested here [What's the proper way to use SQLAlchemy Sessions with Celery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016062/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-sqlalchemy-sessions-with-celery). I've also tried initalizing the db session in celery.py. Neither is working.