Is there an easier way to run async functions in Celery tasks in one event loop?
I have some async code and I need to run it inside the Celery task.
I tried the approach with using asgiref.sync.async_to_sync(), but it turned out that it creates new event loop every time. And it brakes my code since I use SQLAlchemy session pool and there are restrictions about using sessions in different threads and event loops.
It is important to note that I don't care about performance issues. I understand the overheads of using this approach. I just don't want to rewrite my async code to sync.
Trying to run all my async functions in one event loop I created a simple helper module:
import asyncio
import time
from collections.abc import Awaitable
from threading import Thread
from typing import TypeVar


class _SingleEventLoop:
    _loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop | None = None
    _loop_thread: Thread | None = None

    def _enshure_loop_is_running(self):
        if self._loop and (self._loop.is_running() is False):
            self._loop.close()
            self._loop = None
            if self._loop_thread.is_alive():
                self._loop_thread.stop()

        if (self._loop is None) or (self._loop.is_running() is False):
            self._loop_thread = Thread(target=self._eventloop_thread_run, daemon=True)
            self._loop_thread.start()
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def _eventloop_thread_run(self):
        self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self._loop)
        self._loop.run_forever()

    def execute_async_task(self, coroutine):
        self._enshure_loop_is_running()
        feature = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coroutine, self._loop)
        return feature.result()


_single_event_loop = _SingleEventLoop()

R = TypeVar("R")

def execute_async_task(coroutine: Awaitable[R]) -> R:
    """Executes async tasks in single event loop"""
    return _single_event_loop.execute_async_task(coroutine=coroutine)

I can execute my async code like it's shown below:
from single_event_loop_runner.run_async import execute_async_task

@celery_app.task()
def sync_celery_task(param):
    res = execute_async_task(async_func(param))
    return res

It seems to work fine for my use case, but I want to know what the possible negative consequences of using this approach are?
Can I use any easier way to solve my task?
UPD: updated code to use separate event loop (not to use event loop that might be already running in the current thread).

"I use SQLAlchemy session pool and there are restrictions about using sessions in different threads and event loops" this sounds like the important part, but there is no detail in the question about how you set this up in your code. I am guessing maybe the pool is configured "at import time" and that is where problem arises when you call into that code from the celery task?

Hi! Thanks for your interest to this issue!
It is said in the documentation of SQLAlchemy that "should not share the same AsyncEngine with different event loops when using the default pool implementation" (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#using-multiple-asyncio-event-loops).
Their suggestion is "to disable pooling using NullPool", but I think it's not a good solution and it's possible to solve it better..
So, I think the issue is not related to when I create the pool.

so you want to share connection pool between tasks on same celery worker, therefore you want all tasks to use the same event loop, so you made _SingleEventLoop ...and it works but you want feedback on your solution?

Yes, that's right!
I want a feedback (potential problems, limitations of my solution) or any alternative solution that would be better than mine

One thing that comes to mind is how this might interact with the --pool setting of your worker ... I am guessing you would want the solo or processes options. I'm guessing threads or gevent may be problematic. not sure about default prefork. See https://celery.school/the-solo-worker-pool

Actually, I think threads is the best choice for me, since my tasks are async and IO-bound (not CPU-bound). Could you explain why you think that 'threads or gevent may be problematic'? I agree about gevent.

Hmm yes, maybe you're right.

I hope this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016062/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-sqlalchemy-sessions-with-celery
